# Proving an eliptic curve is cyclic, and determining it's order

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elliptic-curves, cyclic-groups

I need a solution with an explanation for the following. Thanks!

Let $E/F_q$ be an elliptic curve and let $P ∈ E(F_q)$ be a point

a. if $n=ord(P)>1/2(q^{0.5}+1)^2$ prove that $E(F_q)$ is cyclic of order n

b. if $n=ord(P)>1/m(q^{0.5}+1)^2$ for $m>1$, what can be said about $|E(F_q)|$?

Comment: Why do you need a solution for this? What did you try? A few suggestions that come in handy. What do you know about the number of points on $E(F_q)$? What do you know about the structure of finite abelian groups? More specifically, how can you read the maximal order of an element of a group written as a direct product of cyclic subgroups? Use whatever you can deduce from those bits!